# how avoid that TFS workitems in complete state are hidden in backlog?

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises. I'd like to kwow if is there any setting in order to prevent TFS to hide workitems in backlog that are in complete state?

Answer (score 0):

No,there isn't the setting to prevent TFS to hide the "Done" workitems in backlog.

If you want to see the complete workitems, you can create a new query with the "**Done**" state included in the clause value. Reference the first screenshot.

Another way to display the complete PBI workitem in backlog is map the completed workitems to "InProgress" or "Proposed". Please follow below steps to do that:

1. [Export the PBI work item definition files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits) (you can use widadmin
   or process editor )
2. Open the WIT file and **create a new State** under `<WORKFLOW><STATES>`,
   also set the `<TRANSITIONS>` accordingly.  (Create the new state "**Completed**" for example here )
3. Save the WIT and import it to project
4. [Export the ProcessConfiguration.xml file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration)
   Open ProcessConfiguration.xml file with text editor and add a state map under `<RequirementBacklog>`  such as `<State type="InProgress" value="Completed" />`
5. Save and import the modified ProcessConfiguration.xml
6. Now you can change the "Done" PBI work item state to the new state 
   "**Completed**", thus the complete PBI work items will not be hided.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user3676571 Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update for this?